# Let $R$ be a graded noetherian domain with $R_0 = k$ a field. If $R$ is integrally closed the $d \mapsto \dim_k R_d$ is a polynomial for $d \geq 1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The situation is this: $R = \bigoplus_{d \in \mathbb{N}} R_d$ is a graded noetherian domain which is integrally closed in its field of fractions, so that $R_0 = k$ (say, for example, the coordinate ring of a projectively normal variety). I then want to show that the hilbert function $$d \mapsto \dim_k R_d$$ is a polynomial for $d \geq 1$. I'm having a lot of trouble showing this, but I'll put some ideas below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

For context, I was trying to use this to show that an algebraic family of projectively normal varieties is very flat. (Hartshorne exercise III.9.5(d)).

Thanks!

ATTEMPT:

First, we remark that $R$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra in degree $1$. Indeed, $R_+ = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is finitely generated by $x_i$ homogeneous of degree $n_i$ since $R$ is noetherian. Moreover, $R$ contains a $n_i$'th root of each $x_i$ since it is integrally closed. As such, we may assume $x_i \in R_1$. Moreover, $x_1$ is irreducible in $R$ since otherwise, it would reduce into a product of homogeneous elements, one of which would be in $R_0 = k$.

We try to prove the claim by induction on $n$ (the number of generators of $R_+$). When $n = 0$, we just have $R = k$ so that $\dim_k R_d = 0$ for all $d \geq 1$. Now assume we have the claim for some $n$ and let $R_+ = (x_1, \dots, x_{n + 1})$. Then, we have an exact sequence $$0 \to R(-1) \stackrel{\cdot x_1}\to R \to R/x_1R \to 0.$$ Since $x_1$ is irreducible, $R/x_1R$ is a noetherian graded domain with $(R/x_1R)_+$ generated by $n$ elements. Now to apply the inductive hypothesis, we would need $R/x_1R$ to be integrally closed which I do not think is true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not correct. Consider a smooth hypersurface of degree $8$ in $\Bbb P^4$, which has Hilbert polynomial $\frac23 (2 x^3 - 9 x^2 + 43 x - 51)$. As a smooth hypersurface, this is projectively normal, and therefore its coordinate ring is integrally closed in its field of fractions. But the 1-graded piece does not have dimension $-10$.

If you're looking for a push in the right direction for III.9.5(d), consider the following hint:

> try showing that $X$ projectively normal implies $C(X)$ projectively normal, and then that cones commute with fibers in this case. There will be more work to do after that.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez oops! Thanks for the correction - I think I've fixed it now.